# Merging tags [widget] and [widgets]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [widget](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widget) and [widgets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widgets) refer to the same type of content and thus should be merged.

Qs tagged [widget](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widget)
Qs tagged [widgets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widgets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been done and a synonym created for `widget`> `widgets`